# openCV k-means call assertion failed

Tags: c, opencv

I'm have read c++ sample from samples folder of openCV source distribution, and, if omit random picture generation, kmeans call looks pretty simple – author even doesn't allocate centers/labels arrays (you can find it [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/kmeans.cpp)). However, I can't do the same in C. If I don't allocate labels, I get assertion error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (labels.isContinuous() && labels.type()
>   == CV_32S && (labels.cols == 1 || labels.rows == 1) && labels.cols + labels.rows - 1 == data.rows) in cvKMeans2, file
>   /tmp/opencv-xiht/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 3094

Ok, I tried to create empty `labels` matrix, but assertion message don't changes at all.

```
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("test.jpg", -1);
IplImage* normal = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_32F, image->nChannels);
cvConvertScale(image, normal, 1/255.0, 0);
CvMat* points = cvCreateMat(image->width, image->height, CV_32F);
points->data.fl = normal->imageData;

CvMat* labels = cvCreateMat(1, points->cols, CV_32S);
CvMat* centers = NULL;

CvTermCriteria criteria = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0);

// KMEANS_PP_CENTERS is undefined
int KMEANS_PP_CENTERS = 2;
cvKMeans2(points, 4, labels, criteria, 3, NULL, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers, 0);
```

The thing that drives me nuts:

```
CvMat* labels = cvCreateMat(1, points->cols, CV_32S);
int good = labels->type == CV_32S; // FALSE here
```

It's obviously one (not sure if the only) issue that causes assertion fail. How this supposed to work? I can't use С++ API since whole application is in plain C.

Comment: That's nice, I posted question 26 sec. ago and already got -1. Would downvoter kindly explain me, what I did wrong?

Comment: I didnt downvote. As far as I know (at least in the past it was that way) you HAVE to allocate all the openCV stuff (output images, buffers etc) in C api manually! About your error: try `CvMat* labels = cvCreateMat(1, points->rows, CV_32S);` instead

Comment: not sure about this one, but looks wrong: `CvMat* points = cvCreateMat(image->width, image->height, CV_32F);` should probably be something like: `CvMat* points = cvCreateMat(yourNumberOfPoints, yourDimensionOfPoints_probably_2_for_2D, CV_32F);` and you will enter x/y coordinates there.

Comment: `points->rows` made assertion failed gone. I don't get why it's not fails anymore since `labels->type == CV_32S` is still false, but it looks like I've got another troubles with passing properly formatted data. Maybe it's good idea for me to read source of c++ or python function to find it out. Thanks @Micka, I think you are answered and can post your answer so I can accept it. @berak: unfortunately, I sticked to that outdated sht, I would love to write in C# instead, but...

Comment: can you try whether `labels->type == CV_32SC1` is true?

Comment: added some code in my answer how you can use the k-means in C-API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the assertion tells you:

1. type must be `CV_32S` which seems to be the case in your code, maybe your if-statement is false because the type is changed to CV_32SC1 automatically? no idea...
2. you can either place each point in a row or in a column, so rows/cols `is set to 1` and the other dimension must be set to `data.rows` which indicates that `data` holds the points you want to cluster in the format that each point is placed in a row, leading to #points rows. So your error seems to be `CvMat* labels = cvCreateMat(1, points->cols, CV_32S);` which should be `CvMat* labels = cvCreateMat(1, points->rows, CV_32S);` instead, to make the assertion go away, but your use of `points` seems to be conceptually wrong.

You probably have to hold your points (you want to cluster) in a `cvMat` with `n rows` and `2 cols of type CV_32FC1` or `1 col and type CV_32FC2` (maybe both versions work, maybe only one, or maybe I'm wrong there at all).

edit: I've written a short code snippet that works for me:

```
// here create the data array where your input points will be hold:
CvMat* points = cvCreateMat( numberOfPoints , 2 /* 2D points*/ , CV_32F);

// this is a float array of the 
float* pointsDataPtr = points->data.fl;
// fill the mat:
for(unsigned int r=0; r<samples.size(); ++r)
{
    pointsDataPtr[2*r] = samples.at(r).x; // this is the x coordinate of your r-th point
    pointsDataPtr[2*r+1] = samples.at(r).y; // this is the y coordinate of your r-th point
}


// this is the data array for the labels, which will be the output of the method.
CvMat* labels = cvCreateMat(1, points->rows, CV_32S);
// this is the quit criteria, which I did neither check nor modify, just used your version here.
CvTermCriteria criteria = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0);

// call the method for 2 cluster
cvKMeans2(points, 2, labels, criteria);

// now labels holds numberOfPoints labels which have either value 0 or 1 since we searched for 2 cluster

int* labelData = labels->data.i; // array to the labels
for(unsigned int r=0; r<samples.size(); ++r)
{
    int labelOfPointR = labelData[r]; // this is the value of the label of point number r

    // here I use c++ API to draw the points, do whatever else you want to do with the label information (in C API). I choose different color for different labels.
    cv::Scalar outputColor;
    switch(labelOfPointR)
    {
        case 0: outputColor = cv::Scalar(0,255,0); break;
        case 1: outputColor = cv::Scalar(0,0,255); break;
        default: outputColor = cv::Scalar(255,0,255); break;    // this should never happen for 2 clusters...
    }
    cv::circle(outputMat, samples.at(r), 2, outputColor);
}
```

giving me this result for some generated point data:

[image]

Maybe you need the centers too, the C API gives you the option to return them, but didnt check how it works.